# Get notification when user pauses dragging

Tags: flutter

is there a way to get notified when user stops dragging over the screen (using `GestureDetector`) when the finger is still on the screen? After lifting the finger I do get `DragEndDetails` event. What I need is sort of "user paused scrolling". Current behaviour is: while moving the finger I do get `DragUpdateDetails` but when I stop dragging (finger on the screen, drag velocity is 0) neither DragUpdateDetails nor DragEndDetails are fired.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just setup a timer (e.g. 1 second) when you receive a drag update event.

If no drag update occurs during that time (or only minimal drag occurs), trigger your callback. Otherwise, if there is significant movement, restart the timer...

When the drag is cancelled or the finger is removed or the widget is disposed, cancel the timer.

Comment: As a work around, yes. But I hoped there would be an API offering this functionality.

Comment: In Flutter you often have to do things yourself. I would call it "feature", not "workaround"